# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added owlCarousel  to my page. but im getting this error. and stuck with it hours.. :(

**HTML code**
[image]

**function in custom.js** 
$("#owl-hero").owlCarousel({

```
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "fadeUp",
    autoPlay: true,
    navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]

});
```

**Reference added** 
[image]

**Screen shot from chrome**
[image: check here error screenshot]

Comment: Can you include the HTML code that loads `owl-carousel` and `custom.js`? Most probably you're loading `custom.js` before `owl-carousel`.

Comment: as @IonicăBizău says please post html code so that we can identify order of JS files

Comment: Please post the `<script ...></script>` part of the HTML, not the carousel slides.

Comment: You have not posted full html code..please post html of JS file including section..

Comment: Please post code as text, formatted, not as images.

Comment: Using `~` at the start of your script src paths feels fishy. What is that supposed to mean? The web server user's home directory supposedly? Also, you need to load jQuery **before** you load anything that uses it, for example any jQuery plugin, and, as far as I know, also before loading bootstrap.js.

Comment: It's a MVC application .. normally we appy ~ sing to take from root

Comment: What does ~ have to do with Model View Controller paradigm?

Comment: @connexo .Net folks use the `~` as a special character that is basically an alias for the application root. It is sort of like `Server.MapPath()`. the MVC pattern has nothing to do with it specifically. It is used in other Microsoft tools like Web Forms. He was just explaining that hs is working in an MS stack, so that is used in url templates. However, i can see (also) that there is clearly an error with is, as it cant seem to locate a lot of resourses, too. i know its weird but `.Net MVC` is actually a brand name like "Silverlight" or "WinForms"

Comment: Why would .NET use a character that the rest of the world uses to reference a user's home directory for that purpose? Screw MS. `/` should be used by everyone to reference the root folder.

Comment: It's only in the context of their templating syntax, as a convenience for folks making `.aspx` files. Not defending or admonishing them, just explaining.

Answer (score 7):

You will get this error if your scripts are out of order. You must load in the right order

1. jquery
2. your fancy carousel (owl carousel)
3. your script calling `owlCarousel()`

(You will also get this if you never imported the owlCarousel plugin in the first place.)

To explain: jquery will put the `$` variable in the global namespace. your owlCarousel plugin will modify the global namespace. Then you may call it as a chainable function in jquery. It must occur in this order, if anything is missing or rearranged it shall break.

To fix: Move jQuery

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to the top of the entire series of loaded scripts. It is currently loaded *after* all of the plugins that need it.

Here is more detail from the Owl Carousel docs:

```
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

You must import assets in that order. See: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Also in your code..make sure you call the carousel on `$(document).ready`, so all your scripts and the DOM are initialized.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-hero").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "fadeUp",
    autoPlay: true,
    navigationText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"     
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest, in this case, wait until the OP posts relevant details so you can answer definitely. Right now, it's all speculation.

Comment: You're sorta right, it is speculation, but not pointless speculation. I'd say it is good advice to help them troubleshoot, and the problem is likely answered in some form by my post.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, most likely you're right. Just giving some advice for cases not as clean-cut as this one :)

Comment: They just posted the load order - jQuery is at the bottom, so I was quick to the gun but this was it. Also, thanks for the advice. It was right this time, but your point is well noted

Answer (score 4):

@isanka in *custom.js* try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
            // your code;
    });
}) (jQuery);
```

As @the_5imian said, include *jquery 1.11.3* before all included scripts.

Comment: Thanks! In my case jquery was included twice and it's hard to remove second definition. So your solution helped!

Comment: I don't know why and how this works, but it worked in my Laravel project with Vue scaffolding. I removed my linked jquery to check if it's already included somewhere in project, it wasn't. Can you please suggest what can be other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Include Jquery in top of the all js files

like below orders

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap-assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And so on...

Comment: Could you please post that code which you have tried or make any js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

this is my custom.js file.

$(document).ready(function () {
    /***************** Navbar-Collapse ******************/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

/***************** Page Scroll ******************/

$(function () {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

/***************** Scroll Spy ******************/

$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
})

/***************** Owl Carousel ******************/

$("#owl-hero").owlCarousel({

    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "fadeUp",
    autoPlay: true,
    navigationText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]

});


/***************** Full Width Slide ******************/

var slideHeight = $(window).height();

$('#owl-hero .item').css('height', slideHeight);

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#owl-hero .item').css('height', slideHeight);
});
/***************** Owl Carousel Testimonials ******************/

$("#owl-testi").owlCarousel({

    navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true,
    transitionStyle: "backSlide",
    autoPlay: true

});
/***************** Countdown ******************/

$('#fun-facts').bind('inview', function (event, visible, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
    if (visible) {
        $(this).find('.timer').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $({
                Counter: 0
            }).animate({
                Counter: $this.text()
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function () {
                    $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
                }
            });
        });
        $(this).unbind('inview');
    }
});
/***************** Google Map ******************/

function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.92757, -83.160207),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

/***************** Wow.js ******************/

new WOW().init();

/***************** Preloader ******************/

var preloader = $('.preloader');
$(window).load(function () {
    preloader.remove();
});
```

})

Comment: It is not in `$(document).ready()`, wrap it like you did your `$('a.page-scroll').` See my edit.