# angular.js TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am using angular js and data-ng-repeat to get data.
Below is my HTML.

```
      <div id="newsslide" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div class="item darkCyan" data-ng-repeat="items in NewsList">
                        Hello
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my JS

```
    $scope.getNewsList = function (Id) {
    var getData = HomeService.getNewsList(Id);
    getData.then(function (_result) {
        $scope.getMediaList(Id);
        if (_result.data.length > 0) {
            $scope.NewsList = _result.data;
            $scope.NewsNoRecords = false;
            $timeout(function () {
                $("#newsslide").owlCarousel({
                    items: 3,                        
                    nav: false,
                    dots: true,
                    rtl:true,
                    // autoPlay: 3000,
                    navText: [
                    "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
                    "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
                    ]
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $scope.NewsNoRecords = true;
        }
    }, function (errorMsg) {
        $scope.loadingDataEntryList = false;
        console.log('Error in getting records - ' + JSON.stringify(errorMsg))
    });
}
```

Data is binding Fine. But it shows

> TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function.

I also tried to run  `$("#newsslide").owlCarousel({});` through pasting in chrome developer console. I got error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
>       at Anonymous:1:18.

Below is library sequence i added, [jQuery library was in head tag before this image. and thats why it cause problem]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZsuV.png)

I have searched a lot. Please help. Thanks

Comment: check whether you have added the reference library in app initialization module  and also it comes up in the page ( by looking into page source)

Comment: Show the `<script>` tags loaded in your main HTML file (ie `index.html`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814426/uncaught-typeerror-owlcarousel-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can be the potential reason.

1. It seems you have not added Jquery
2. Or Jquery is added after Angularjs
3. haven't added the "owl carousel" JS file

You need to add jquery before angularjs.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ... 3. They haven't added the *"owl carousel"* JS file. 4. They're including another `jquery.js` file **after** the plugin one

Comment: Or he might have added  jquery file  after the owl carousel file. So, he has to load jquery beforer owl carousel file

Comment: Hi guys, i have addded an image of library sequence. Please have a look again

Comment: Yes @Ved bringing the jquery near to all libraries resolved the issue. Before this jquery was in head tag.   Thanks ....

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery near and above of all libraries resolved the issue. Before this, The jquery was in head tag. Thanks ...